# Can we us Flutter's Google mobile ads package for showing ads except admob in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Can we use
[google mobile adds package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) for flutter to show ads  through bidding from Facebook + unity or Facebook + AppLovin
Or Facebook + startup ads etc.
But not Admob ads. Is it possible with this package?

Answer (score 1):

You need mediation for that. You integrate Ad Units to display ads, if you integrate ad units from Facebook only Facebook Ads will display and so.

Comment: ok means if we did not include meditation and  admob ads ad units then fb ads will be shown.? and what about using facebook ads meditation with other networks other than admob? is it possible with this package?

Comment: There is a process, you have to setup the Ad networks i.e register your app. You should go through the Ad Mob Docs and Github Google ads repo. Your all doubts will be cleared.